# How to map minus key to german ß-letter for brazilian portuguese Dell Inspiron 15 laptop keyboard layout?

Tags: dell, keyboard-layout

I successfully mapped ö, ä and ü to ç, ~, and ´, following
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

However, I did not manage to map the minus and underscore key to the german ß.
In the br file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols, I changed line 161 to
`key <BKSL> {[minus, underscore, U00DF,U1E9E ] };` 
line 225 to
`key <AD12> {[minus, underscore, U00DF, U1E9E]};`̣
and 96 to
`key <AB09> {[period,greater, U00DF]};`

all without success. The key is on the number row (second from top) in 11th position. Also tried applying it to other keys, which does not work either.
Edit: This seems to be because ö, ä and üalready exist in the brazilian layout, while ß does not. Is there a way to integrate it, inspite of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Backup Your Current Configuration:

> sudo cp -r /usr/share/X11/xkb /usr/share/X11/xkb_backup

Edit the Appropriate Keymap File:
Instead of modifying the existing keymap file, it's better to create a custom keymap file to avoid conflicts and issues during system updates.

Create a new keymap file, e.g., custom, in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols directory:

> sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom

Define Your Key Remappings:
In the custom file, add the following lines to define the remappings for the minus and underscore key to the German "ß" character:

> key  { [minus, underscore, U00DF, U1E9E] };

Edit the evdev.xml File:
To make the changes visible in the keyboard layout settings, you need to edit the evdev.xml file.

> sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml

Locate the  section for the German layout  and add the reference to your custom keymap file within the  section:

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>de</name>
    <!-- Other configuration options -->
  </configItem>
  <variantList>
    <!-- Other variants -->
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>custom</name> <!-- Add this line -->
      </configItem>
    </variant>
  </variantList>
</layout>
```

Update the Keymap Configuration:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data

Reboot

After completing these steps, you should be able to use the minus and underscore key to type the German "ß" character when using the custom keymap.

Comment: thanks! In the evdev.xml file I find only three occurences of custom:  <layout>
      <configItem>
 <name>custom</name>
        <shortDescription>custom</shortDescription>
        <description>A user-defined custom Layout</description>
      </configItem>
      <variantList/>
    </layout>     where axctly do I need to the reference? and the reference is xml or de custom?  My custom file sould not be a copy of the br file?  And do I need to add the key postition after "key" (AE11)?

Comment: *do I need to add the reference